# execute windows cmd code has no output in rust

Tags: windows, rust

```
let output =     Command::new("cmd")
    .arg("/C")
    .arg("ipconfig")
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
for out in String::from_utf8(output.stderr).iter() {
    println!("............{}", out);
}
for out in String::from_utf8(output.stdout).iter() {
    println!("............{}", out);
}
```

there is no output message in windows11。 i can't found the problem, who is known?

how solved this probelm that i can get the windows cmd command output?

Comment: What if you used `Command::new("ipconfig")`?

Answer (score 4):

You have a funny way of unwrapping errors. Try this code:

```
use std::process::Stdio;
use std::process::Command;
fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("cmd")
        .arg("/C")
        .arg("ipconfig")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
    println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8 (output.stderr).unwrap());
    println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8 (output.stdout).unwrap());
}
```

This program will crash with an `Utf8Error` because the output of `ipconfig` is not valid UTF-8 (unless your native locale is English). You can get around that with [`from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) which will replace non-UTF-8 characters with the replacement character `U+FFFD` (�), or using a crate like [`encoding_rs`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs) to convert from your local character encoding to UTF-8.